# Inserting in postgresql table from db2 trigger

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, db2, sql-insert

My problem is the following one:

I have a db2 database and a postgres database. They are in different servers. Every time i add a new record into a db2 table, it should be added immediately to the postgresql as well.

I was thinking doing it via a trigger. But i have no idea what to put inside it to insert into the postgresql. I have read maybe i can call an external stored procedure, but I'm not quite sure if it is what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java Stored Procedure**

Yes, you can create a stored procedure, for example in Java. You call this stored procedure from your trigger. And inside the Java stored procedure, you create a connection to postgresql and insert the received values from DB2 and insert them in postgres. I think you have to deal with two connections, one from DB2 and the new one for postgres.

There are many information about Java Stored Procedures:

- http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245945.pdf
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510law/

**Federation: Postgres wrapper**

Another approach is to create a wrapper for Postgresql. Currently, IBM provides many connectors via InfoSphere Federation server, but I have not ssen any for Postgres nor Mysql.
However, you can create your own wrapper. The documentation is here:

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp
- Federation > Developing for federation > Developing connections to custom data sources.

If you want to create an OpenSource project for a postgresql wrapper, I will be interested to participate.

Comment: One thing to consider with either approach is how to deal with errors. I assume if the postgres insert fails, then the DB2 insert should rollback too. For a trigger, maybe it should be done as 'before insert' so the whole insert can be aborted if there's a postgres issue?

Comment: "before insert" or "after insert" does not impact the transaction, if the stored procedure trhows an exception/sqlstate when an error occurs in the execution. In both cases, the transaction will be rollbacked in DB2.

Comment: However, if the stored procedure wrappes all errors (try catch), then DB2 could commit, but there will not be a corresponding value in Postgres.

Comment: These problems about synchronizations don't happen when ussing a wrapper. It already takes in account all those cases.

Comment: @AngocA thanks for your help. It seems that is the right way.